# how to compact Json in Struct Golang

Tags: json, go, struct

```
package questionnaire

import (
    "encoding/json"
)

type Items []Item

type CreateData struct {
    Items []Item
}

type Item struct {
    Id        enter code herestring `json:"id"        required:"true"`
    CompCd    string `json:"compCd"    required:"true"`
    OrgCd     string `json:"orgCd"`
    QstnId    string `json:"qstnId"    required:"true"`
    QstnIdSeq string `json:"qstnIdSeq" required:"true"`
    CustId    string `json:"custId"`
    AnsDts    string `json:"ansDts"    required:"true"`
    AnsRout   string `json:"ansRout"   required:"true"`
    QCd01     string `json:"qCd01"`
    QKey01    string `json:"qKey01"`
    QStc01    string `json:"qStc01"`
    QCat01    string `json:"qCat01"`
    Pont01    string `json:"pont01"`
    PCat01    string `json:"pCat01"`
    Comt01    string `json:"comt01"`
    QCd02     string `json:"qCd02"`
    QKey02    string `json:"qKey02"`
    QStc02    string `json:"qStc02"`
    QCat02    string `json:"qCat02"`
    Pont02    string `json:"pont02"`
    PCat02    string `json:"pCat02"`
    Comt02    string `json:"comt02"`
    .
    .
    .
    QCd50     string `json:"qCd50"`
    QKey50    string `json:"qKey50"`
    QStc50    string `json:"qStc50"`
    QCat50    string `json:"qCat50"`
    Pont50    string `json:"pont50"`
    PCat50    string `json:"pCat50"`
    Comt50    string `json:"comt50"
}
```

I'm newbie. I just learn go language a few day before..
My problem: How to compact this Item struct block. If i write from QCd01 to QCd50 this code can run but so bad!
    Sorry I'm not good at English.

Comment: If they're all strings, why not use a map?

Comment: thanks bro, but if i use map, what it will become?

Comment: myMap := make(map[string]string) Checkout https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action and https://gobyexample.com/maps

Comment: how to convert json string into map[string]string?
myMap := make(map[string]string)
myMap["Id"]=‘json:"id" required:"true"‘
myMap["compCd"]=‘json:"compCd" required:"true"‘
strJson := []byte(`{"items":{"id":"01","comCd":"0001"}`)
if err := json.Unmarshal(strJson, &myMap); err != nil {
  fmt.Println("ERROR")
}
fmt.Println(myMap) // ERROR

Can this code will work?
i tried but it's cant work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied and pasted the code in your comment. It was missing the ending `}` to finish the json string. Also, you need a struct to tie the `items` map to. Here is a working playground link.

EDIT: I didn't realize there would be more than one "items", which I should have assumed given the plural name. Here is an updated playground link that takes care of that.

https://play.golang.org/p/5T2C6KrVOD

Comment: thanks you for answer, but if i wanna check validate `json:"id"        required:"true"`, how can i check it?

Comment: Anything that is required, you would just have check manually if it exists in the map. I updated my playground link with such a check.

Comment: i change myMap with many "items". When i use json.Unmashal(strJson, data), why data became map[]. I wanna loop by "items" key then json.Mashal(data) to write file.
Playground:https://play.golang.org/p/1hglmTXxBZ

Comment: @HoangTan I modified the playground link to take account for the fact that "items" can have more than one `item`. I should have known, but none of your examples actually had more than one `item`, so I just spaced it.

Comment: I understood. Thanks you very much. 
When i search created data, i received map didn't sort, not like the same input data. I knew map[string]string didn't sort.
If it is map[string]int or map[int]string i can sort it, but it's map[string]string. How can i sort map[string]string to become the same inputdata?

Comment: Build a slice of key value pairs using `for key, value := range mp { ... }` then sort by the key using a sorting library. If it is JSON, why does it need to be sorted?

Comment: I create files with the format data,  when i search and read it from created file, i want output data have the same format. Because exist data bring that format then i want it the same. 
If i use a slice to sort map, the format will be changed.

Comment: You are trying to do something that isn't part of the JSON specification. JSON objects have no specific order and are actually related to dictionaries or maps in the spec. JSON arrays are ordered, so your array of `items` will be in order, but the objects in the array carry no such guarantee. If you want to enforce ordering, you will need to do it manually. Even different languages will often order JSON objects differently. The same JSON string input is not guaranteed to == string output. See the portion just after the first paragraph here: http://www.json.org/